# php -v giving php: symbol lookup error: php: undefined symbol: rl_on_new_line on centos

Tags: php, centos7

```
php -v
```

gives

> php: symbol lookup error: php: undefined symbol: rl_on_new_line

I updated `libedit-20090923-3.0_1.el5.rf.x86_64`

Comment: You have libedit for centos 5, while you have centos 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an el7 system then there should be no packages from el5 installed.
Please run this command:
`rpm -qa | grep "el[56]"`

And replace any packages that are listed by the el7 version (like libedit).

Comment: rpm -qa | grep "el[56]" give libedit-20090923-3.0_1.el5.rf.x86_64
rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 and yum remove  libedit-20090923-3.0_1.el5.rf.x86_64 is asking me to remove  libedit-20090923-3.0_1.el5.rf.x86_64 package and 89 other packages including php and several others

Comment: Well, then you need to do that, and install the correct version of the package afterwards. I'm assuming that your tag "centos 7" is correct?